# UITextField valueDidChange-Event

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, key-value-observing

Is there a way to catch a "valueDidChange"-Event for a Textfield? oO

I've got a modalView with an UITextField.

When the UITextField is empty, the "Done"-Button in the NavigationBar should be disabled
and when there is Text entered, it should become enabled.

Right now the only way to accomplish this by using the "textFieldShouldReturn"-Method.
This works but is simply horrible for usability.

Isn't there a way to check the requirements every time a letter is being entered or removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Implement `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW9).

Comment: The Problem here is:
-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
gets called BEFORE the character has been inserted.
What I need would be a call AFTER the character has been inserted.

I could still work with this, if i knew how to use the range and replacementstring parameters to construct the resulting total string

Comment: If anybody cares: the solution is to catch the control event "EditingChanged" with addTarget:selector:controlevent:

Comment: @Infinite: You may want to put that as an answer and accept yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody cares: the solution is to catch the control event "EditingChanged" with addTarget:selector:controlevent: ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have a `UITableViewController` with `self.editButtonItem` which is enabled only if the `UITextField.text` has text in it. It's a way of ensuring that the user doesn't press "Done" before he/she has filled this `UITextField` with something. I think this is exactly what you're looking for. Here's how I did it:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Logs for seeing patterns, if you so please
    NSLog(@"replacementString length = %d",string.length);
    NSLog(@"textField.text = %@",textField.text);
    NSLog(@"range = (%d,%d)\n\n",range.location,range.length);

    if (string.length) {
        self.editButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    } else if (!string.length && textField.text.length == range.length) {
        self.editButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I hope that helps